# Can I redirect media urls (not attachment pages) to the post parent?

Tags: php, redirect, attachments

I have a really unorthodox use case, perhaps.

We have a set of pdf files which our colleagues would like to track downloads for. We have been using our web server logs to get code 200 requests for these urls (not precise data-wise, but it is what it is), but we're moving to shared hosting and the new hosts set up would require us to implement a log streaming tool to get at this data. We want to avoid that if possible, so I'm looking for solutions to work around this.

I know the usual use case around media files is people wanting to prevent people from going to the media pages. That's not what I want to do.

Here's what I want to do:

Let's say I have a website [www.ilovepeanutbutter.com](http://www.ilovepeanutbutter.com).

- The website has a pdf with the url https://www.ilovepeanutbutter.com/wp-content/uploads/delicious_cupcakes.pdf.
- delicious_cupcakes.pdf is attached via custom field to a post called "Delicious Cupcakes" in a post type "recipes"  with a permalink https://www.ilovepeanutbutter.com/recipes/delicious_cupcakes

Using PHP, can I redirect https://www.ilovepeanutbutter.com/wp-content/uploads/delicious_cupcakes.pdf to https://www.ilovepeanutbutter.com/recipes/delicious_cupcakes if the referrer isn't https://www.ilovepeanutbutter.com?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use PHP, you'd have to do some sort of redirect for URLs to `/uploads/` to a handler script. Depending on how many of these situations you have, it may be easier/simpler to create a redirect for each file; could potentially be done on upload, interfacing with a plugin like Redirection.